# Return a List to a View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, return

I want to be able to find the users login id for my app and then match that to all rows that contain the users login id in my database.  After I have found all that match I want to then display the results that are true and then pass those along to the view.  Here is what I have so far;

```
public ActionResult YourEvents()
{   
   //users email who is logged in
        var userId = User.Identity.Name;
   //list of users who have created events that match the name of the user logged in.
        IEnumerable<Event> userListing = db.Events.Where(x => x.EventCreator == userId);
        foreach (var e in userListing)
        {
    //return all that match 
         return View(e);
        }
            return View("EventErrorCreateMessage", "Event");
    }

    public ActionResult EventErrorCreateMessage()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

My plan was to use a foreach statement to find the email id in the database and then use that to display whole rows in the listing of the view.

Please let me know if you need a more code.  cshtml file was created using scaffolding.

Thank you!

Comment: Possibly remove the `foreach` and just do `return View(userListing.ToList());`

Comment: return view(e) will return only the first match.. you need to return the whole IEnumerable as a start...

Comment: Thanks for the response Ric.  Tried it but it seems to just be returning all items in the data base regardless of who created it.  I am wondering if an If statement would help?

Comment: why are you returning a view for each e that matches ? Why not construct a list and send that list to the view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make your view strongly typed against `IEnumerable<Event>` by typing

`@model IEnumerable<Event>` on top of the view, then change your action method with this:

```
public ActionResult YourEvents()
{
   var userId = User.Identity.Name;
   IEnumerable<Event> userListing = db.Events.Where(x => x.EventCreator == userId);
   return View("EventErrorCreateMessage", "Event", userListing );
}
```

**OR**

By using `ViewData`

```
        public ActionResult YourEvents()
        {
           var userId = User.Identity.Name;
           IEnumerable<Event> userListing = db.Events.Where(x => x.EventCreator == userId);
           ViewData["list"] = userListing;
           return View("EventErrorCreateMessage", "Event");
        }
```

And retrieve it in view as

```
@{IEnumerable<Event> list = (IEnumerable<Event>)ViewData["list"];}
```

Comment: figured it out!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yield return` in another method. Like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Event> GetUser(string userId)
{
   var users = db.Events.Where(x => x.EventCreator == userId);
   foreach (var user in users)
   {
      yield return user;
   }
}

public ActionResult YourEvents()
{
   var userId = User.Identity.Name;
   var users = new List<Event>(GetUser(userId));
   return View(users);
}
```